# How to force google benchmark to run multiple iterations?

Tags: c++, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I use google benchmark to test two C++ functions. One runs for ~630,000,000 ns and one runs for ~1,000,000,000 ns. But both only run one iteration. How can I force the benchmark to run more iterations? I would like it to run at least 10 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who encounter similar problems:

There is no way to directly control the number of iterations for a benchmark. Instead, one can use benchmark_min_time to indirectly configure the number of iterations a benchmark runs. A simple way to do this is:

```
BENCHMARK(YourBenchmark)->MinTime(10); // 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 7):

You can actually do

```
BENCHMARK(YourBenchmark)->Iterations(100); // will run for 100 iterations
```

Note that this will run the benchmark *exactly* 100 times. I couldn't find a way for it to run *at least* a number of times

Comment: Cannot believe I miss this. Maybe I was reading an older document or so? Good to know this, and thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think.